# Django-piston takes huge response time in read

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-piston

When returning result from the read method, it takes a huge amount of time to generate/send response (for like 30,000 records with 6 columns, it takes around 14 seconds).

1. Is this fine and it normally takes this much time?
2. If this ins't fine, what can I do to reduce the time? What/Where could I refer to?

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have defined the *fields* parameter to fetch many related objects(Objects with foreignkeys,onetoonekeys and manytomanyrelations to the object being fetched). This will slow down your response. Can you post your code?